# heroku に push しようとするとエラー: runtime (python-3.8.2) is not available

Tags: python, heroku

Pythonのファイルをherokuにプッシュしたいのですが、以下のメッセージが表示されてしまいます。`runtime.txt` に書くべきバージョンが違うのでしょうか？

[image: python-3.8.2 is not available]

公式サイトには「Python 3.8.2 now available」とあるので使えるはずなのですが、うまくいきません。

PCのPythonは以下の通りです。これがダメなのでしょうか？

```
$ python -V 
$ Python 2.7.16
$ python3 -V
$ Python 3.8.2
```

回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python の **マイクロバージョン** にも注目してみてください。バージョン表記のうち、A.B.**C** の部分です。

ローカル環境では 3.8.**2** のようですが、push 時のメッセージに出ている URL を開いて確認すると、サポートするのは 3.8.**12** と記載されています。

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support

> #### Supported runtimes
>
> - python-3.8.12 on all supported stacks

[3.8.12 は 2021-08-30 にリリース](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3812/) された現時点での最新版ですが、[3.8.2 のリリースは 2020-02-24](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-382/) で古いバージョンになります。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。

よく確認できていませんでした。
runtime.txtに「3.8.12」のバージョンで記載して
念の為3.8のPythonを入れ直しPATHを通したらうまくいきました！

数日悩んでいたので嬉しいです。
ありがとうございました。